# Db Date Partition Change

Tags: database, oracle, partitioning

I have a table lets say `Orders(id, ORDERDATE)` and this table is daily partitioned on `ORDERDATE` column.

When I change the `ORDERDATE` column of some records one week after inserting theam ,do records are moved to other partition?

Using Oracle 11g...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. You have to enable it:

```
alter table orders enable row movement;
```

Some docs say something "BEWARE row movement must be implemented!!!" and so on. Row movement is not so dangerous. You have to just keep in mind that, you can not insist on ROWIDs stored somewhere, as ROWID will change when row is moved.
But you most probably are not using ROWIDs anyway.

Also the movement(update) is internally implemented as pure row delete and insert. So it will probably generate more redologs. Than if it was a "real" table update.

Also this might "waste" some space. The partition segment is never reduced even if all rows are moved out.